# laravel @foreach putting numbers before each entry

Tags: php, laravel

how to add a number after foreach entries in LARAVEL please help? What I want to do is after foreaching

1. ARTICLE 1
2. Article 2
3. Article 3

Comment: Paste some code. That will really help us :p

Comment: which Laravel version?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the `$key` in your `foreach` loop.
Lets say you have your data in `$array` variable. To get the index number you can use the below method.

```
@foreach ($array as $key=>$value)

{{$key+1}}.{{$value}}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that in Laravel 5.3+ you can just do

```
@foreach ($array as $item)
    {{ $loop->iteration }} // For starting at 1
    {{ $loop->index }} // For starting at 0
@endforeach
```